# forEach loop only works on the last item

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a button the multiple divs on a page. Why does it work only on the last item?

```
const columns = document.querySelectorAll('.hcolumn');
const button = document.createElement('div');
button.innerText = 'Expand text';
button.classList.add ('button');

columns.forEach( column => {
column.append(button)
});
```

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/3dyuval/pen/GRmyQwQ)

Comment: Think about it: how often are you actually calling `document.createElement('div')`?

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're are appending the same `button` element each time which is a single reference so it gets removed from previous element and gets appended to next one. You also need to create a new button everytime like so :-

```
const columns = document.querySelectorAll('.hcolumn');

columns.forEach( column => {
const button = document.createElement('div');
button.innerText = 'Expand text';
button.classList.add ('button');
column.append(button)
});
```